# SQL Server Query on todays date using datetime2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, datetime2

I have a SQL Server database that when I open it on screen I want it to just show the records that have been added today.

I have the date stored in a field called DateAdded and it is of DateTime2 data type.

I tried this

```
string dateAdded = today.ToShortDateString();

string query = "SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, AppStatus 
FROM Customer     
WHERE DateAdded ='" + dateAdded + "'";
```

This displays no records which I would assume as it has the time attribute stored with the date.

I searched online to try and find the answer, but none seemed to be specific for just records added today.

I'm also going to need to search on date ranges based on user inputs, and it could be on any range for eg view records from 09/01/2013 to 18/03/2013.

What is the best way to go about writing the sql query for this?

EDIT - My Answer

The answer Carl gave worked, but I didn't understand how to change the values so I could have different date ranges. I though I should post my final result on here, which I based on the answers I received, so it might help someone else. :)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            int year = date1.Year;
            int month = date1.Month;
            int day = date1.Day;

            string dateAdded = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " ";

            int year2 = date2.Year;
            int month2 = date2.Month;
            int day2 = date2.Day;

            string dateAdded2 = year2 + "-" + month2 + "-" + day2 + " ";

            string query = "SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, AppStatus, DateAdded FROM Customer WHERE DateAdded >= @date1 AND DateAdded <= @date2";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date1", dateAdded + "00:00:00");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date2", dateAdded2 + "23:59:59");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(holder);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should use a **parametrized query** and use a parameter for the date you want to add; that parameter can be of type `DateTime` and thus handle your data

Comment: Please, for good practice, use parameters. Or better yet use SQL with a  to achieve this. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1) AS [MM/DD/YY] http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Convert is awful. Should us the DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0).

Comment: Except that that gives you a time as well which ToShortDateString() doesn't.

Comment: It gives you midnight, toshortdate doesn't have a time in the string but will have 00:00:00 as the time in SQL

Comment: Upon further inspection that seems to be his problem. Helps to read things in their entirety it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OP's responses changed the SQL to this

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2, @EndDate DATETIME2

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()+1), 0)

SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, AppStatus 
    FROM Customer     
    WHERE DateAdded >= @StartDate AND DateAdded < @EndDate
```

This will get anything on the current date (you can replace Getdate() with a date of your choice for re-usability)

Comment: I would caution against using inline SQL however. That way leads to potential SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Are you storing the time with your dates? If that's the case then no it wouldn't work and you would need to do a between midnight/23:59:59 approach

Comment: Yeah as it says i'm using the datetime2 field which stores the time aswell. :)

Comment: Edited my response to take into account your answer

Comment: SQL Server gave me a syntax error with that so I tried, i needed to add DateAdded again after AND. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I originally did it as a between but then realised you would fetch anything created at exactly midnight on the next day. Will edit now

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, AppStatus FROM Customer WHERE DateAdded >= @DateAdded";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: I strongly advise for this method, because, first it uses parameters and you won't have to mess with date format and current culture, second you are safe from malformed sql and injections.

Comment: Except it doesn't work with my problem of course, it would if it was just a date field I imagine.

Comment: @saintsfanuk: It was a simple arithmetic error. In the where clause you have to test for *greater or equal* and not only *equal*. After that change this statement should also work.

Comment: Ah I see now, sorry I thought it was because of the datetime2 field I am using, you are correct this also works.

Answer (score -1):

Try your SQL query like below..

**Query:**

```
string query = "SELECT CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, AppStatus FROM Customer
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateAdded, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateAdded, 101)";
```

**Parametized Command :**

```
string dateAdded = today.ToShortDateString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query ;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", dateAdded);
```

Comment: DateAdd is more efficient than convert as there is no data conversion. Also using convert on the left side of a where clause is a massive no no.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith But the User save Date info with Date and time... Without converting how to match the Date...?

Comment: See my answer, doing a convert on the actual data will prevent SQL from using any indexes or statistics on the column.